# How to display all the values of matching key in one cell

Tags: excel, formula

I need to get all the values matching from another tab.  Below is the example:  I will be entering all the values in Tab 2 manually.  As well as I will be entering the Categories (Column A) in Tab1.
I want the Values (Column B) in Tab1 to be populated.

Tab1 :

```
_________________
CATEGORY  |VALUES|
-----------------|
AA1       |1     |
          |2     |
-----------------|
AA2       |5     |
-----------------|
BB1       |3     |
-----------------|
BB2       |4     |
          |6     |
```

Tab 2:

```
 
CATEGORY  |VALUES  |
-------------------|
AA1       |1       |
-------------------|
AA1       |2       |
-------------------|
BB1       |3       |
-------------------|
BB2       |4       |
-------------------|
AA2       |5       |
-------------------|
BB2       |6       |
```

Comment: a pivot table would be a good way to get the same result without any manual input, just saying.

Comment: @nutsch, A pivot table would sum the values, not concatenate them

Comment: @SeanCheshire, not if you put them as a row field

Comment: Hi Nutsch / Sean Cheshire,  Thanks a lot.  I tried with Pivot table, but there are two problem, 1) It is not dynamic, i may change the tab 2.  2) values are listed below the categories.  Is it possible to address these problems?

Comment: Hi, can any one help me in this please???

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @nutsch, a PivotTable is the obvious choice:

[image: SO20381217 example]